# .net core web not rendering CSS

Tags: c#, html, css, .net, razor

I am building an application in .net core 2.0 Razor pages and cannot get the site.css file to render what I want it to. I am string to customize the _layout.cshtml file by changing the nav bar. When I run the project the CSS does not apply going so far as to when I inspect the page the css that is being rendered is not even the file that I have changed.

The CSS code is:

```
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
}

.navigation {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

/* Wrapping element */
/* Set some basic padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

div.table {
    display: table;
}

div.table > div.thead {
    display: table-header-group;
}

div.table > div.tbody {
    display: table-row-group;
}

div.table > div.thead > div.table-row,
div.table > div.tbody > div.table-row {
    display: table-row;
}

div.table > div.thead > div.table-row > div.table-heading {
    display: table-cell;
    font-weight: bold;
}

div.table > div.tbody > div.table-row > div.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
}

/* Hide/rearrange for smaller screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    /* Hide captions */
    .carousel-caption {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

and the _layout.cshtml is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - AdeptFrontEnd</title>

    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" runat="server"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" runat="server" type="text/css" />
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="nav flex-column navigation">
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
            <li><a asp-page="/Network/Index" class="navbar-brand">Adept</a></li>
            <li><a asp-page="/Network/Index">Network</a></li>
            <li><a asp-page="/Network/Index">Network</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    <environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-K+ctZQ+LL8q6tP7I94W+qzQsfRV2a+AfHIi9k8z8l9ggpc8X+Ytst4yBo/hH+8Fk">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the solution I get page that looks like:
[image: Site after build with the site.css file that is being rendered]

How do I get the CSS to render properly?

Answer (score 1):

You put the site.css in the environment exclude. Comment that out and see if it works.

Comment: That worked. Can you explain why that would be as I haven't changed any of the  boilerplate code except for what is in the <body> tags

Comment: I believe it's because you're testing it in a "development environment" while at the same time telling the program to exclude that .css file for development environments

Comment: If that's how the project comes out of the box, to me, that seems a bit of a silly thing to do.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the exlude comes with a `site.min.css` out of the box and you accidently deleted the `.min`.

Comment: @Marco I haven't deleted the site.min.css as i can see it is nested in the project explorer. The issue I had with that was that I didn't want to update the .min and if the .min gets compiled then that wasn't working.